# Object Name in CONTAINS not found in Database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-text

One of the packages I inherited contains following Oracle Text function :

contains ( title, 'query ', ' transform (( tokens, "**SCHEMA1.fuzzy_thesaurus**"  ))  )

But when I query the DBA_OBJECTS, I don't see an OBJECT_NAME = 'FUZZY_THESAURUS".

But the package is VALID, which means SCHEMA1.fuzzy_thesaurus does not refers to database object.

I don't have much knowledge of Oracle Text.

What does this **SCHEMA1.fuzzy_thesaurus** refers to ?

Comment: Do you see `OBJECT_NAME = 'fuzzy_thesaurus'`?

Comment: nope. select * from dba_objects where object_name = 'fuzzy_thesaurus' returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It is a thesaurus which is used by Oracle Text to expand your queries. You can find it with the following query:

```
-- be sure to be connected on SCHEMA1 
select *
  from CTX_USER_THESAURI 
where UPPER(THS_NAME) = UPPER('fuzzy_thesaurus');
```

To find more about thesaurus and OT use the official Oracle docs:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/cthes.htm#g1009100